# golang no permite llamar scanf más de dos veces

Tags: input, go, scanf

por que en golang no me permite usar el scanf mas de dos vesces?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    
var a,b,c int
   
fmt.Scanf("%d/n",&a)
    
fmt.Scanf("%d/n",&b)
    
fmt.Scanf("%d/n",&c)
    
fmt.Println(a+b+c)
    }
```

Comment: el programa solo me deja ingrersar el valor de a y b y al finalizar el tercer valor lo deja en 0 ..alguien sabe por que pasa esto

Answer (score 1):

`Scanf` funciona esperando cumplir con el patron que le asignaste, entonces, tu le dices que sera un `%d/n`, pero el problema es que `/n` seria una constante lo que tu quieres hacer es indicar que lea los numeros antes de un salto de linea, por lo tanto tu sentencia de escape es `\n`.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a, b, c int

    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &a)

    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &b)

    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &c)

    fmt.Println(a, b, c)
}
```